# Computer dialer for GoToMeeting

Tags: gotomeeting

My phone headset is much more reliable and has better sound quality than my Internet connection and speakers.

Is there a way to have the internal fax modem dial into a GoToMeeting meeting?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean, use the fax modem, controlled by phone-like software, dial into the voice line of a GoToMeeting meeting?

The problems would occur if your computer then looks to that connection as the source for internet, because obviously, the GoToMeeting voice line does not provide digital data but analog audio only.

If you have telephone software that allows this setup, I don't see how it would be an issue.

Comment: Yes, I would like to use the fax modem to dial out rather than having to type the long string of numbers again and again.  I do not understand the issue with the about the source for Internet because the computer has a NIC connected to a broadband router via local lan.

Comment: The problem is that, when you somewhere using a dial-up modem, your computer will generally be looking to that connection for an internet connection. Unless the software managing the modem can differentiate between a connection for a voice call versus a connection for internet, you're going to lose your internet connection. It all depends on the software you use.